# Spring Animation on Vector Path in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-vectordrawable, animatedvectordrawable

[Spring Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/spring-animation) can be applied to views. Is there any way I can apply Spring Animation on path of a `VectorDrawable`. I need some physics based Animation on Vector path. How can do that? Any suggestion

Thanks in advance.

Comment: define "Vector Path" - you mean `android.graphics.Path`?

Comment: path is a tag used in vector drawables to define path

Comment: no, you cannot use that "path"

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do but check RichPath, it may help you. https://github.com/tarek360/RichPath